# Is it possible to combine Spring JpaRepository and some CustomRepository in one reusable interface?

Tags: spring, jpa

I know how to customize one individual repository (from [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behavior)), but I'm curious is it possible to combine JpaRepository and one or more custom repositories (with implementations) and then extend from this one repository.

```
public interface MyCustomRepository<E> {
    void customMethod();
}

@Repository
public class MyCustomRepositoryImpl<E> implements MyCustomRepository<E> {
    void customMethod() {
        // impl
    }
}

public interface MyReusableRepository<E> extends JpaRepository<E, Long>,
                                                 MyCustomRepository<E> {
}

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends MyReusableRepository<User> {
}
```

This example brings me the following error:

> Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Failed to create query for method public abstract void com.my.pckg.MyCustomRepository.customMethod()!
>   No property customMethod found for type User!

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.customize-base-repository

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want to change the base for all of the repositories but only for a couple of them.

Comment: That specifies the base *implementation*. Your repository *interfaces* can still extend from JpaRepository, or PagingAndSortingRepository, or CrudRepository, and thus not expose the additional methods present in the custom base repository implementation

Comment: Okay, but it still will be one single _base_ while what I want is some small reusable part. Not sure that the approach with base _implementation_ is a proper solution for such case.